Problem with my streamlit & gemini api app
So I'm trying to biuld a simple streamlit app with gemini api in order to transform natural language to sql and then provide me the data from the database that i need.
The problem is everytime i ask a question i get this error: Error with Gemini model: module 'google.generativeai' has no attribute 'generate_text'

this is my code:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv() ##load all environment variables

import streamlit as st
import os
import sqlite3
import google.generativeai as genai

## Configure our API KEY
genai.configure(api_key=os.getenv("GOOGLE_API_KEY"))

##Function to load google gemini model and provide query as response
def get_gemini_response(question, prompt):
    model= genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')
    response=model.generate_content([prompt[0],question],stream=True)
    return response.text


## Function to retrieve query from sql database
def read_sql_query(sql,db):
    conn=sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    return rows


## Define your Prompt
prompt=[
"""""
You are an expert in converting English questions to SQL query!
The SQL database has the name STUDENT and has the following columns - NAME, Class,
SECTION \n\nFor example ,\nExample1 - How many entries of records are present?,
the SQL command will be something like this SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDENT ;
\nExample 2 - Tell me all the students studying in Data Science class?,
the SQL command will be something like this SELECT * FROM STUDENT where 
CLASS="Data Science";
also the sql code should not have ''' in beginning or end and sql word in output
"""

]    

##Streamlit App
st.set_page_config(page_title="I can retrieve Any SQL query")
st.header("Gemini TO Retrieve SQL Data")

question=st.text_input("Input: ",key="input")
submit=st.button("Ask the question")

##if submit is clicked
if submit:
    response=get_gemini_response(question, prompt)
    print(response)
    data=read_sql_query(response,"student.db")
    st.subheader("The response is")
    for row in data:
       print(row)
       st.header(row)

